Finding an polynomial in $x, y, z, t$ whose leading term cannot be in $k[y]$
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $\omega_1$ be a special degree function on $k[x,y,z,t]$ generated by $\deg_{\omega_1}(0) = -\infty$, $\deg_{\omega_1}(\kappa)=0$, for all $\kappa\in k\setminus\{0\}$, $\deg_{\omega_1}(x)=-1$, $\deg_{\omega_1}(y)=2$ and $\deg_{\omega_1}(z)=0=\deg_{\omega_1}(t)$. $A$ is a subring of $k[x,y,z,t]$ such that $k\subseteq A$, $A$ is factorially closed, algebraically closed in $k[x,y,z,t]$, $A\not\subseteq k[x,z,t]$ and the trascendence degree of $A$ over $k$ is $2$.
I am trying to show that there must be an element $f\in A$ such that its leading term under $\deg_{\omega_1}$ is not in $k[y]$.
I have already tried by contradiction supposing that all $f\in A$ are such that their leading term under $\deg_{\omega_1}$ is in $k[y]$. By the trascendence degree $2$, there are $2$ irreducible algebraically independent terms, $f$ and $g$ in $A$ with that property. I separated all terms in $y$ with constant coefficients as $f_1$ and $g_1$ respectively. Then, $f_1$ and $g_1$ are algebraically dependent. Hence, there is a polynomial $P\in k[X,Y]$ such that $P(f_1,g_1)=0$. Then, I evalluate $P(f,g)$ and tried to reach a contradiction. Using induction over the $\deg_{\omega_1}$ of $f$ and $g$, I got a contradiction but only supposing that $\deg_{\omega_1}(g)\le 1$ or odd otherwise $\deg_{\omega_1}(P(f,g))$ is not less than either $\deg_{\omega_1}(f)$ or $\deg_{\omega_1}(g)$ and cannot guarantee that its leading term is not in $k[y]$. There I get stuck.
